# Importing org.quartz and org.slf4j in Netbeans Maven Project

Tags: maven, netbeans, import, quartz-scheduler, slf4j

I'm looking to import support for `org.slf4j` and `org.quartz` in a maven project in Netbeans. However, I'm not able to figure out the exact steps. I'm unclear as to how should I configure these two packages (through their jar files) as artifacts.

My present Netbeans structure looks like this :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rightclick on the dependency node, select Add dependency.   In the query field, type `org.quartz-scheduler`.  In the list that appears in Search Results fold open the node `org.quartz-scheduler : quartz` and click on the version you want (I'd go with 2.1.6 for now).

For `org.slf4j` the sequence is comparable.

Comment: Great!  By the way, what I described is actually identical to Mirko's explanation, the only difference being he adds the dependencies to the pom file using a text editor, my version uses IDE assistance for the same purpose.  Remember both techniques as you'll probably end up using a mix of both depending on the context.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you want to add them as maven dependencies in `pom.xml`?

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
    <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.6</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Netbeans has excellent integration with Ant and Maven and will pick the dependencies up by itself.